# A question of approach.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I would like to get your input on the 'correct' approach to tackling Spivak's problems.
To illustrate, let me pick the simplest problem from Chapter 1.

(At this point of Spivak's book, he has covered only the first 12 properties of numbers.)

> if $ax = a$ for some number $a\neq 0$, then $x = 1$

So, here is my answer

$$ax = a$$ $$ax\cdot a^{-1} = a\cdot a^{-1}$$$$(a\cdot a^{-1})x  = a\cdot a^{-1}$$$$x  = 1$$

And here is Spivak's answer

> $$1  = a\cdot a^{-1} = a^{-1}(ax) = (a\cdot a^{-1})x  = 1\cdot x = x$$

I want to understand the difference in the (mathematical) thinking and approach of Spivak and mine. Is it merely his is simpler ( a good thing)? or some very subtle but important concept which is obvious to you, the mathematicians on this board, and those of us endeavoring to enter this discipline.

Comment: It's hard to say much without more context.  What are $a,x$? Are you assuming commutativity across the board? Associativity?  Axioms matter.

Comment: If only associativity is being assumed, then I would write $1=a^{-1}\cdot a=a^{-1}\cdot (a\cdot x)=(a^{-1}\cdot a)x=x$, which is different from either argument you presented.

Comment: @lulu  I wrongly assumed people would understand this is a question assuming one is starting out using Spivak's Calculus. I tried to add some more context to the question. Either way what I am interested in is why one - like yourself - would adopt that particular approach, in essence, what the thinking behind your answer is, as opposed to mine ( wordy and not very mathematical)

Comment: Stating that it appears early in Spivak does not tell me what Axioms are being assumed.  Note that my argument only assumes Associativity. Yours, on the other hand, appears to assume that $x\cdot a^{-1}=a^{-1}\cdot x$ which is only obvious if you assume Commutativity.  Thus, my argument holds more generally than yours appears to.  That's why I prefer it.

Comment: An even simpler argument would be $ax=a\implies a^{-1}\cdot (a\cdot x)=a^{-1}\cdot a\implies x=1$. Again, that one only uses Associativity.

Comment: @lulu  Thank you for indulging me. So, to directly answer your question, the axioms which I believe are assumed at this point include Associativity, Commutativity and Distributive ( although not sure if this is regarded as an axiom). At this point, the identities ( additive, multiplicative and their inverses have all been introduced, and thus  assumed).

Comment: Ok.  So, then, I'd say all the proofs we mentioned are valid.  I still prefer the ones which use fewer Axioms because, as I mentioned, those arguments will work more generally.  But that's a technical point.  If all you want is to prove the claim in the given context then any of the arguments are fine.  As a general rule, simplicity is always good.  But it's not reasonable to expect people to find "simple" proofs on their first try.

Comment: @lulu  Thanks for that.

Comment: Just try to be diligent about making sure each step is justified, either by one of the "12 properties of numbers" or one of the later results. When I began Spivak, I'd catch myself using algebraic techniques I'd learned elsewhere that weren't yet proven in the text.

Comment: As lulu pointed out, if you can prove the same result while relying on one fewer axiom/property/assumption, this yells you something significant. It could be that the property here you're demonstrating about $1$ relies on additive commutativity. That it doesn't is meaningful.

Comment: You might later encounter a system that has its own form of additive associativity, but not commutivity, and in which a similar property for the Multiplicative Identity holds, ex. matrices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Spivak's argument is too compact for a beginner.
Yours is essentially correct. It would be much better with more words:

Suppose $a \ne 0$ and
$$
=.
$$
Since $a \ne 0$ it has an inverse (previously established) so
$$
⋅^{−1}=⋅^{−1}.
$$
Then using the associative and commutative laws (previously established)
$$
(⋅^{−1})=⋅^{−1}
$$
so using the meaning of $a^{−1}$ and the fact that $1$ is a multiplicative identity,
$$
=1 .
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer.